# Function declaration is block scoped

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

It is said that function declarations are **block-scoped** but the code below cause confusion in my mind. Please if anybody knows some article which reflects the true behaviour of function declaration.

```
{ // Enter a new scope

  console.log(foo()); // prints hello
  function foo() {
    return 'hello';
  }

}
foo(); // {A} // prints "hello"
```

If functions would have been block-scoped then why should line {A} have printed "hello" in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with the code above is that it ran in sloppy mode, thats why everything went well. But in strict mode line A will return error. Hence, functions are block-scoped.

```
'use strict';
{ // Enter a new scope

  console.log(foo()); // prints hello
  function foo() {
    return 'hello';
  }

}
foo(); // {A} // throws error
```

Comment: In "strict" mode, if `foo` was defined prior to entering the inner block scope, it would revert to its previous definition upon leaving that scope.

Comment: @suprcat You are correct but here I asked this question on context of the code example I provided and I got my confusion resolved here.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's good to know that if `foo` had been defined in the outer scope, the latter call wouldn't have thrown an error, but would have silently invoked the earlier function (which might or might not have been what was intended).